# Reading CSV file in powershell to get info from Active directory

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a new question for you. So I just got a list with employee names and IDs, I am supposed to write a script that can look up the employee and search for their department info in active directory and then add it to the CSV file.

I thought that I can just look at all the employee numbers, pad them to 5, look for that number in AD, use that to look up the department and add that to the CSV.
I can get most steps done by typing the commands manually but cant figure out how to make it all work automatically using the whole list.

.[image: My CSV looks like this]
I would like to add the retrieved department info in the next line over.
My code so far looks like this.

```html
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$csvlines = import-csv .\test.csv
foreach($line in $csvlines)
{
$ID=$line.EmployeeID;
$padding = "$ID".PadLeft(5,"0")
$filter = "ID -like '$padding'"
$getdepartment = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties Department | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Department
Write-Host “ID=” $ID, $getdepartment;
}
```

I am messing up somewhere, could you guys please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, show example of what the result should looks. why do you need to pad it anyway? isn't the source employee id is equal to the employee id in your AD?

Comment: The reason why I needed padding is because the IDs in AD all have to have 5 digits. Therefore, most of the IDs have 00034 for example. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody needs to do something similar, I just figured out how to solve my problem. I will share the code with you guys.

```html
$csvlines = import-csv .\list.csv
foreach($line in $csvlines)
{
$first = $line.FirstName
$last = $line.LastName
$ID = $line.EmployeeID;
$padding = "$ID".PadLeft(5,"0")
$filter = "EmployeeID -like '$padding'"
Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties UserPrincipalName, Department, Title, EmployeeID | Select-Object GivenName, Surname, EmployeeID, Department, Title | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path .\new.csv"
}
```